# radRibbonBar RightToLeft Property

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-radribbonbar

In radRibbonBar (Windows form, Telerik 2010, Visual Studio 2012, C#) When I set RightToLeft property to Yes there isn't any problem in designer and i have this:

[image]

but when the project is run the ribbon button hide the close button, like this:

[image]

Any idea?
Can i remove this button?

Comment: RTFM :) http://www.telerik.com/forums/hiding-start-button-in-ribbon

Comment: @Alex Thank you very much.Is there another solution except hiding the button?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to hide window's title bar and replace it with your own that has the controls on the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at first, it seems that only the ribbon control is in RightToLeft mode, but not the form, as its buttons are not moved.

I would suggest using RadRibbonForm (http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/forms-and-dialogs-ribbonform-overview.html), which will take over the task bar as well. You can modify this behavior with the AllowAero property of the ribbon form.